# APT says libsdl2-2.0-0 is not available

Tags: apt

When I enter the following command

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0-0
```

I got the following error message

```
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Aucune version du paquet libsdl2-2.0-0 n'est disponible, mais il existe dans la base
de données. Cela signifie en général que le paquet est manquant, qu'il est devenu obsolète
ou qu'il n'est disponible que sur une autre source
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.

The content of my `sources.list` is:

```
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-proposed main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
#deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

I have already searched for similar problems without success.

---

Sorry for my english, I will try to answer ...
When I put this command :

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0
```

I have this answer:

```
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Note : sélection de libsdl2-2.0-0 pour l'expression rationnelle « libsdl2-2.0 »
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
```

But I have an application (albion) that needs SDL2 and the application keeps putting me an error message :

```
    For working Audio in Albion Online SDL2 is required,
please install it with 'sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0-0'
```

---

OK sorry,
I have changed the content by:

```
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main
```

I think is the good content but I am not sure.

Comment: Your `sources.list` is for Ubuntu 12.04 (precise). How did that happen? See [How do I restore the default repositories?](//askubuntu.com/q/124017) for some methods to restore the default repositories. 16.04 is Xenial

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong before, `libsdl2-2.0-0` is still available for Ubuntu 16.04 (see the [official package description](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/libsdl2-2.0-0)). As Zanna stressed, your problem is related to the fact that your `sources.list` is not compatible with your current OS version. Have you upgraded from `12.04`?

Anyway, to restore your `sources.list` file you might want to follow the instructions given by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/192388/738202).

Comment: OP has repositories for precise in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, which is probably the real problem here

Comment: @Zanna I'm sure it does not help indeed, though after trying OP's command to install SDL, I got the same error message, whereas my `sources.list` looks OK.

Comment: Yeah, I'd doubt the newer repo has that version! Your advice here is good. But they'll need to fix the sources first, because the precise repos have been moved